# SSRS Datamethod writes file and needs permisson from which user?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, ssrs-2012

I have a Report from AX.

My report uses a Business Logic, in this, there is a Datamethod, which writes some Data to a File. This file is located in a shared folder.

To test my method i give everybody read/write permission to the shared folder and it works fine.

Now we have to change the permissons and my question is which user needs read/write permissons on the shared folder?

Every user, which uses the report?

A Service user, like the entried user for the "SQL Server Reporting Services"?

A AX Service user?

I searched a lot, but there is nothing that helps me, so I hope on you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I perform a similar process the solution for me was set read/write permissons for every user to execute the report. For AX service user didn't set any permisson and work fine.